# How can I install a GUI and browser on a ubuntu server and connect it from Windows 7?

Tags: firefox, gui

I hope to apply a ubuntu server at https://www.vultr.com/. I hope to install a browser such as Firefox or Chrome on the ubuntu server and remote connect from Windows 7.

I think I should to install a GUI first.

1: How can I install a GUI on the  ubuntu server ?

2: How to install a browser such as Firefox or Chrome on the ubuntu server ?

3: How to connect to the ubuntu server via Windows 7 remotely so I can access Firefox or Chrome ?
    You know that putty.exe can only connect to ubuntu server with text model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by 'GUI', you are referring to a desktop environment. First you need to decide which DE is right for you. This is something you should research for yourself as it can be rather subjective. Some of the common DEs can be installed with one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install mate-desktop
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

If you're looking for something light, the lubuntu-desktop package would be the one to choose. Other than that, different features and appearances make it difficult to recommend DEs for other reasons.

If you want to install an internet browser, pick one of the two:

```
sudo apt install firefox
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

For everything mentioned above, if you're installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu, you can just use the desktop version with the minimal installation option set.

As for connecting to an Ubuntu system from Windows, one of the most common ways to do this is to use [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) on Windows. You can then use the IP address of your Ubuntu system to establish the connection, and use the username and password you've set up on the Ubuntu system when connecting via PuTTY.

You might need to install the openssh-server package on Ubuntu if you're unable to connect.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a beginner of Linux, I can use PuTTY , it seems that I can only input command line in PuTTY. I hope to display remotely GUI of lubuntu-desktop just like I connect to remotely Windows 2012 server UI from local Windows 7 , how can I do?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do remote desktop, but the easiest one for you would be Teamviewer. Visit their website and you should be able to set things up easily enough on your own.